# Array.prototype.push.apply unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Array.prototype.push.apply to merge two lists.

```
c = Array.prototype.push.apply(a, b);
```

However, this does not merge the arrays when the second one is `[]`.

for instance if

```
a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
b = []
```

`c` will be `3`

Why is this happening?
Shouldn't `[]` be treated like any array?

Comment: The push method return the length of the new array

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? What is so unexpected by the result `3`? What inputs did you try where it "worked"?

Answer (score 1):

Just use Array.prototype.concat:

```
c = a.concat(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly correct, because [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will return the length of the new array.

If you want a new array which has the concatenated value then use [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you may have been trying to achieve is using `push.apply` to append `b` to `a`. However this method means that you don't have to create a new array `c` to hold the result.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4], b = [5];
a.push.apply(a, b); // a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem is the `.apply`, it ask the contetx (a) and an array of values (b), if you pass an empty array it acts like you have passed no values...

Try this:

```
c = Array.prototype.push.call(a, b);

//c = 4
```